# How to add headers to existing variable

Tags: powershell

I've pulled some information from running

`$sites = Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1.company.com -ScriptBlock {appcmd.exe list site}`
This returns

```
 C:\> $sites

SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,state:Started)
SITE "test.company.com" (id:2,bindings:http/*:80:test.company.com,http/*:20011:,state:Stopped)
SITE "test2.company.com" (id:7,bindings:http/*:80:test2.company.com,state:Stopped)
SITE "test3.company.com" (id:8,bindings:http/*:80:test3.company.com,state:Stopped)
```

Using some regex I filter these down to

```
$siteswithbinding = $sites | select-string -Pattern '[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
$siteswithoutbinding = $siteswithbinding -replace '[:0-9:]'
```

This gives me a variable that looks like

```
 C:\> $siteswithoutbindings

test.company.com
test2.company.com
test3.company.com
```

I'm looking to add a "header" to this column as well as create a new column and populate it with the server name, IE

```
 C:\> $siteswithoutbindings
Hosts                 Servers
---                   ---
test.company.com      Server1.company.com
test2.company.com     Server1.company.com
test3.company.com     Server1.company.com
```

I'm unfamiliar with the verbiage so I'm not sure how to word this correctly.

Comment: Looks like your code is missing a step, where does $cleansites come from?

Comment: Same goes for "server1.company.com", is that what you refer to as "computer.somedomain.com" in the example?

Comment: @PMental I made an edit to correct the variable names and the server name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PowerShellGuy has the correct answer most likely, but if you want to do it with the base you have already you can accomplish it using this:

```
$Server = 'computer.somedomain.com'
$sites = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {appcmd.exe list site}
```

then do whatever you need to get $cleansites to look like your example, after that do:

```
$Output = foreach ($Site in $cleansites) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Hosts = $Site
        Servers = $Server
    }
}
```

and you should have your desired output in $Output, like this:

```
Hosts             Servers
-----             -------
test.company.com  computer.somedomain.com
test2.company.com computer.somedomain.com
test3.company.com computer.somedomain.com
```

And if you need to do this for several servers, it's only a matter of some extra foreach-logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it as an option, I'd like to introduce you to the `WebAdministration` [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps), and `Get-Website`

Use `Get-Website` to get the sites, then format the output of `invoke-command`, grabbing the name, and PSComputerName properties.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    Get-Website

} | ft Name, PSComputerName
```

Edit: since WebAdministration isn't working for you you can do this

```
$banana = Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock {
    $sites = . appcmd.exe list site
    $siteswithoutbinding = $sites | select-string -Pattern '(?<=SITE\s")[\w\.\s]*(?=")' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }

    foreach($site in $siteswithoutbinding)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Host = $site
            Server = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        }
    }
    
} -HideComputerName | select -Property * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId

$banana
```

Which results in this

```
Host              Server       
----              ------       
Default Web Site  server1
test.company.com  server1
test2.company.com server1
test3.company.com server1
```

P.S I ran into issues with your regex, so I made my own, feel free to change it back to suit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately the environment in which these servers live in cannot be altered, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @huzer1 I'm not saying to modify the remote servers. If the remote servers have IIS installed, they most likely have the WebAdministration module available. You can check by invoking this on the remote machines `Get-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Tools`. If that shows as installed, then you can run the code in my answer with no problems. If not, then let me know, and I'll edit my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, this appears to work perfectly, but when I run it remotely through Invoke-Command, it's returns an error which a little bit of googling pins it as a bug that's fixed in later versions.

The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
+ CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Website], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetWebsiteCommand

With that said, I'm still curious have to add a header to an existing variable that doesn't have one.